# Removing SRAM Red Chainrings

Tags: maintenance, chainring, sram

This is almost certainly very simply, but how do you undo the chainring bolts on the SRAM red chainset? I can fit a 5mm (or 8mm can't recall now) hex head into the black screws, but they just spin on the spot. I have tried both the front and back. Some seem harder to spin than the others, but I can't work out how to remove them.

[image: SRAM red crankset]

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there's a sort of nut on the back, with a slot for a screwdriver.  Difficult to reach without a specially shaped screwdriver, though.

Comment: Ahh thanks - you got me thinking. Not quite right, but a 6mm on one side, and a 5mm on the other actually does it

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that that would likely be the updated design, but my bikes are too old to have it.

Comment: @j.s. - Can you add your comment as an answer and accept it?

Comment: Yeah, that was the "specially shaped screwdriver" I was talking about.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, you need to use a 6mm hex on the front and a 5mm on the back. Using these both at once will engage the bolts, and they will undo